# Finding Real roots of a polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all real values of $a$ for which the equation
$(x^2 + a)^2 + a = x$ has four real roots.

Can someone help me with this? I have no idea how to start this.

Comment: It seems as if $a<-0.7$... See [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ob4rl4d5pw).

Comment: Is this pre-calculus?

Comment: if it has $4$ real roots, you should be able to write it as a product of two quadratic polynomials with real roots (i.e. positive discriminant)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $(x^2+a)^2 + a - x = (x^2 + x + a + 1)(x^2 - x + a)$.  When do these quadratic factors have two real roots each?